# How to pass a class to a method and create it there

Tags: dart

I have such an example of a model:

```
class BirthdayModel {
  List birthdays;

  BirthdayModel({
    @required this.birthdays,
  });

  factory BirthdayModel.fromJson(json){
    return BirthdayModel(birthdays: json['data']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'birthdays': birthdays,
    };
  }
}
```

I want to transfer multiple models into one method:

```
exampleMethod(model: BirthdayModel);
```

and then in this method call the constructors or methods of the passed class

```
exampleMethod(@required model){
  return model.fromJson(data);
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the way you write it.

You cannot pass a *class* as argument. Even type arguments only pass *types*, so you cannot use static members that way.

What you can do is:

```dart
T exampleMethod<T>(T createModelFromJson(dynamic json)){
  return createModelFromJson(data);
}
```

and call it as :

```dart
var birthday = exampleMethod(BirthdayModel.fromJson);
```

There is no way to access the `fromJson` programmatically - it's not an instance method so there is no *interface* for it. Static methods must be accessed explicitly.

(I'm ignoring `dart:mirrors` because you probably won't have access to those).

Comment: Thanks, making the fromJson method static, this solved my question, dart: mirror can also solve my question in a more elegant way?

Comment: The `dart:mirrors` library is not available when compiling for Flutter or the web, so it's rarely useful. If you are only running the Dart (server) run-time locally, then mirrors can be used to take a class type and look up and call a static method from that type's declaration. I wouldn't call it *elegant*, though.